# Under what conditions will healers switch targets?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been using healers lately, which I haven't really utilized much before. I've noticed that they will sometimes switch targets, even when their original target still lives.

What conditions are needed for healers to switch targets?

Comment: This is an interesting question! Sometimes it seems that healers will switch from their primary target even when their primary target is not at full health, which is the most curious case.

Comment: Maybe it is based on who has the least health at the time

Comment: @PythonMaster nope. She targets whoever is in range

Comment: @Alex: Of course, there's also the instances where she'll ignore targets that are in range to follow who she has originally targeted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience, healers primarily follow other units that are within their range. If you have two units outside the range of a healer with no target in range, the healer will go to the closer one and follow it, regardless of the health values of the units. While this makes healers "dumb" they are not totally useless, because if there are multiple units within range, I believe the healer will switch targets once the unit it is targeting has full health. If the target has higher health but is not fully healed, the healer will follow it even if there is another unit closer to death and within range. If there is a target within range and it has full health, the healer will still follow it instead of leave to heal an injured unit out of the healer's range.

Granted, I haven't used healers in months because their housing cost is so high, so my experience could easily be out of date.

Comment: This sounds about right at first glance. So, if I have a group of healers following my Queen, and my Queen, who moves fairly fast, repositions herself for a new target, my healers, who are slow and may be in the middle of healing, may reevaluate their targets and get distracted by some nearby giants?

Comment: That's possible. I haven't unlocked my queen yet, but it happens with hog riders all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Healers switch targets when their original target is out of range, or when their original target dies.

Answer (score 0):

Healers will target the troop that takes the most housing space near them that is taking damage. For example, if a hero (25 spaces) is at full health with the healers on them and a golem (30 spaces) nearby starts taking damage the healers will switch to healing the golem.