# Who does healers follow?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When I do queen walk I take 2 or 3 healers with me and first thing, I put the queen and attach healers to her. But sometimes healers leave the queen and follow BK or giants, and that sucks. I want healers to be on the queen throughout. What things should I take care of for that. I like surrounding queen with archers, although healers dont go for archers, but once they did. How can I avoid that.

May be queen on one side and giants and BK from other side. Nowhere near queen, right? How about archers, is it safe to surround queen with archers and barbs?

In general case, if i drop 2 giants on each corner of a side on a village and put one healer right in the middle, how does healer choose where to go? Do they have prefernce too, healing the one with higher hitpoints or something?

Comment: I've already asked this question... and I've yet to get a satisfactory answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267955/under-what-conditions-will-healers-switch-targets

Comment: This seems to ask "from the get go, who will the healer target, first". The dupe seems to ask "why would a healer **change target**". Seems like two very different questions, when I actually read them.