# what are the chances of healer to target P.E.K.K.A or Archer Queen?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Assume that there is a attack going on, with 3 P.E.K.K.As and an Archer Queen. Now, I planed to throw a healer in the middle of the Archer Queen and a P.E.K.K.A locked on two air defences, what are the chances that healer targets Archer Queen and left the P.E.K.K.A (If the other P.E.K.K.As are locked in the core )??

EDIT- I have seen [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267955/under-what-conditions-will-healers-switch-targets) but it have'nt helped as my question is different, as if the healer is thrown at a distance that the Archer Queen and P.E.K.K.A are at same distance which will healer heal first?? (I probably want the healer to target the Archer Queen).

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272983/who-does-healers-follow), which is a duplicate of [that](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267955/under-what-conditions-will-healers-switch-targets)

Comment: i dont think it is, my ques is something diffrente @DanmakuGrazer

Comment: Wrong, your question is a more specific case of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272983/who-does-healers-follow) question.

Answer (score 0):

**Healers prioritise Heroes.** So whenever the Archer Queen will come close enough to the Healers, they will change their target to her.